# How do I find a column-wise count that has a particular value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `attendance`

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
+ p_id  | day_1 | day_2 | day_3 | day_4 | day_5 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
+  1    | P     |  P    | P     | A     | A     |
+  2    | P     |  A    | A     | P     | P     |
+  3    | A     |  A    | P     | P     | P     |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Here `p_id` = `people.id` foreign key

And a table `people`

```
+------------+
+ id   | gend|
+------------+
| 1    | M   |
| 2    | F   |
| 3    | M   |
+------------+
```

I would like to get a final output like this which contains the total absentees with their respective count of males/females:

```
+---------------------------------------+
+  day     | total_a | males  | females +
+---------------------------------------+
+  day_1   |  1      | 1      | 0       +
+  day_2   |  2      | 1      | 1       +
+  day_3   |  1      | 0      | 1       +
```

and so on

I am unable to think where to begin with such a query. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Stop. Redesign your schema.

Comment: @Strawberry yep that was my first reaction too to the problem. Unfortunately 20 other apps rely on this, changing schema will be a huge cost-factor. That is in Phase-2 however, slowly phasing out this horrendous DB design.

Comment: It sounds like a huge but necessary cost factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you need to unpivot the `attendance` table, then `join` and reaggregate:

```
select a.day, sum(a.pa = 'P') as total,
       sum(a.pa = 'P' and p.gend = 'M') as num_males,
       sum(a.pa = 'P' and p.gend = 'F') as num_females
from ((select p_id, day_1 as pa, 'day_1' as day
       from attendance a
      ) union all
      (select p_id, day_2, 'day_2' as day
       from attendance a
      ) union all
      (select p_id, day_3, 'day_3' as day
       from attendance a
      ) union all
      (select p_id, day_4, 'day_4' as day
       from attendance a
      ) union all
      (select p_id, day_5, 'day_5' as day
       from attendance a
      )
     ) a join 
     people p
     on p.id = a.p_id
group by day
order by day;
```